# How to avoid firing same query multiple times to DB with different param values from Java code

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a problem statement where in I have to fire a select query to the database multiple times, based on the number of elements. Certain parameters of the query change from element to element.

There are two approaches that I came up with.

1. Fire the select Query in a loop with the changed param values.
   Sample query : `Select * from Employee where employee_ID in (?) and dept_Id = ? and years_of_exp = ? and skill = ?`

The param that doesn't change is years_of_exp.

2. Fire a select Query with the non-changing parameters and the loop through the 
   result set to filter out the data based on the parameters that change.

Note: I am using Spring Data JPA. I cannot use Stored procedures.

It should also be generic where if the DB is changed, no code change will be required.

Is there any better way to achieve the same with better performance.

Thanks.

Comment: Those are pretty much your two options... Either filter in the query each time you execute, or load *all* data into memory and filter in the code.  The former is almost always vastly preferred to the latter.  Why is the former not working for you?  What problem have you observed?  Also, the statement *"It should also be generic where if the DB is changed, no code change will be required."* is entirely a non-starter.  Nobody can make that guarantee, and it doesn't have anything to do with the question itself.

Comment: If you would like to do all filtering on the DB side, you can make a query with a large custom condition. Compose it of parts like this: `(employee_ID=? and skill=? and dept_id=?) OR (employee_ID=? and skill=? and dept_id=?) OR ...` and bind parameters to `?`s for each condition.

Comment: Thanks @David for the answer. The first approach is firing the query multiple times(I enabled show sql) and it is taking as long as 3 sec to finish looping through the elements. I understand It depends on the number of times the loop executes, the amount of data present in the DB and the query param itself. But still I wanted to check if I am missing on anything which can make it faster.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I thought of that too, but i think it would be the worst solution... That way, not only you give the DB a more complex query to filter according to your needs, but you'll still need to filter java-side, so you actually filter the data twice. It's better IMO to run different concise filter queries and save the results as needed.

Comment: @BackSlash I agree with you. As I need to make sure the result set is set to the element again.

Comment: @BackSlash Don't worry about sending complex conditions to RDBMS. DBs know how to filter, it's their bread and butter. If you do the condition right, you wouldn't have to filter anything on Java's side.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight - Read the question. My point was not on the complex filtering, it was about filtering twice. *I have a problem statement where in I have to fire a select query to the database multiple times, based on the number of elements* - This means that the OP needs to have different resultsets based on some conditions. If you put all conditions inside one big query, you'll still have to filter java-side to separate the results based on single conditions, so your optimization on making the DB filter for you is useless.

Comment: @BackSlash That's not filtering, though, in the sense that no data that comes back from RDBMS gets thrown away.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight You do throw away some records. If you need 3 different result sets matching 3 different conditions and you solve it by having a single resultset which matches all the three conditions, you'll have to loop over that resultset three times (one for each condition) and save only records that satisfy the current condition. It's a useless overhead. Better run 3 different queries without filtering loops on the java side.

Comment: why use native query? JPA has nice joins fetch, if You correctly find dependencies on common data

Comment: @jacek Cz it's just an example.

Comment: @BackSlash do you have a better solution or approach than the others that I have mentioned?

Comment: @TusharBanne No, I'd go with the first solution; that way you have multiple specific queries and you get exactly the results you need, without having to filter them again with java. Also, filtering is faster DB-side, so I'd choose this approach.